# How to set icon and background color to Combox item in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to improve the layout of my Combobox items in my Windows Phone 8.1 applications. By the default, the combobox items will be something like that:

[image]

I want to set, for each items, an icon and background, which depends on an attribute of the object inserted (may be green if is ok, orange if something isn't ok, red in case of error). How Can I do ? So I want something like that, where also the blue background, will be set for a specific case (the previously example should be clear).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a DataTemplate for the ComboBox items. You'll probably have to use a converter for the background color.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfProperties}" SelectedValuePath="Id">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="{Binding ColorName, Converter={StaticResource StringToBrushConverter}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/> // "ms-appx:///Assets/image.png" for example
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```